# Spring Boot 2.0 / Hibernate MySql Alter table syntax Error

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, alter-table

With Spring Boot 2.0, when using property `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto: update`, hibernate is generating an incorrect alter table ddl statement.  Worked fine in Spring Boot 1.5.7.  I have tried the various mysql dialects, with no success.

Here's an example of the sql that is being generated:

```
alter table testDatabase.analyte_definition add column action_level decimal(8,2)
```

The problem is the database name `testDatabase" is be prepended on the alter statement.  The correct syntax is:

```
alter table analyte_definition add column action_level decimal(8,2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what was going on here.  Turns out my local database name had a period  in it, ie; local.prod20190319.  Changing the db name to local_prod20190319, solved the issue. Having the period in the db name worked in SB 1.5.x, but not in SB 2.x.